# Push the output of YOLOv8 into an Excel file

Tags: excel, yolov8

I have trained the data and now i want to put all the predict i had into excel file . This is the code i used :
import pandas as pd

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import numpy as np

model = YOLO('./runs/classify/train/weights/last.pt')  # load a custom model
results = model('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/phanloai/public_test')  # predict on an image
names_dict = results[0].names
probs = results[0].probs.data.tolist()
input_detail = [names_dict, probs, names_dict[np.argmax(probs)]]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names_dict': input_detail[0],
    'probs': input_detail[1],
    'max_prob': input_detail[2]
})

output_excel_path = './content/gdrive/MyDrive/phanloai/ketqua.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_excel_path, index=False)

print(names_dict)
print(probs)
print(names_dict[np.argmax(probs)])`
```

The code runned and printed 3 values i want but these values didn't in the excel file ? Is there any error that i don't know ? Please help me !! Thank you a lot